# How do I bring the Floating Action Button outside the app and make it run as visible,moveable and clickable background service?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

So I need my app that has a switch, which when turned on, should create a FAB. This should then run like a background service, over all other apps, after the main activity/app is closed. So anywhere I touch the FAB, it should be clickable,moveable and should draw over all apps.

Comment: checkout this: http://developer.tooleap.com/overview/

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look.

Comment: Do you mean like facebook messenger when minimzed ?

Comment: @penta exactly. But  no need of opening a floating window on click., just a simple clickable, moveable button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the following projects

https://github.com/JustinScott/AppFloater

https://github.com/vickychijwani/BubbleNote

https://github.com/sezeryesiltas/chat-head-demo

https://github.com/callmekarthik/FBChatHeadExample

Comment: please accept the answer and upvote if it suited you :-)

Comment: done :) Question.. Is changing this to suit material guidelines easy? Or does it need a lot of code to be modified. I hope its just a layout/drawable change.

Comment: ah ok. Bummer :/ I guess I can figure it out once I get an idea of how this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an activity with transparent windows background set in theme, no status bar, no toolbar, no layout, just the FAB. You cannot bind the FAB to your background service. A service does not have a GUI. You need to have a running activity while your button is showing.

Comment: thanks. How can I make the FAB moveable, so it doesn't lay over the FAB's of other apps?

Comment: This is something completely different form the original question. I'm sure you'll find some answers on how to make a view draggable. Basically, you need to implement on touch listener on your FAB and set its coordinates according to your MotionEvent object, whilst action is DOWN or MOVE. When the action is MOVE_UP, you stop dragging the view

Comment: Got it. Thank you sir.