# How to create a button that floats on top of home screen or any other app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How to create a button like in Shazam that floats on top of home screen or any other app like this in flutter[image]

Comment: As far as I know, that's Android-specific behaviour, so you would need to implement this natively using Android, Flutter does not support such a thing out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer btw do you know what this type of button is called in android?

Comment: You can find some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32946971/how-do-i-bring-the-floating-action-button-outside-the-app-and-make-it-run-as-vis/32947301

Comment: This package might be what you are looking for: https://pub.dev/packages/floaty_head

Answer (score 1):

Try this package
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window

You can floats your app on top of home screen and on other apps.